# bash script to find the results from multiple input files which are using 'samtools' to a new output csv file

Tags: bash, shell-script, bioinformatics, spreadsheet

I have query related to Bioinformatics. I have multiple bam files, from each bam file i should find out number of mapped reads from each bam file with id's, for doing it i have the command

```
$ samtools view -c -f 1 -F 12 HG00173.chrom11.ILLUMINA.bwa.FIN.low_coverage.20111114.bam
```

for this i am getting output in some numbers as 1222456.

My requirement is, I should get  the output for all the input bam files in a csv file with 2 columns with naming column 1) Bam-id , column 2) No_of_mapped_reads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
parallel --tag samtools view -c -f 1 -F 12 ::: *.bam
```

If this is not what you want, please update your question with sample input and sample output.

Comment: thank u ..it worked perfectly .. Absolute on point

Comment: also if possible can you please explain the command how it is working..? i mean each function of parameters used..